# File System for virtualization server

Tags: debian, filesystems, virtualization, storage

I am going to be running a Proxmox (a virtualization distro based on debian wheezy) server. There is going to be 1 or 2 KVM vm and 2 - 3 openVZ containers running at any given time.

I want to be able to have the following capabilities:

```
 1 dynamically add and subtract from a VM or container storage. 
 2 expand the total host storage as my needs grow 
 3 have some redundancy (only for some of the files and I do have offsite backup)
```

The Hardware will be:

```
 1 a Q87 motherboard running an i7 3.5 gig quad core with hyperthreading
 2 32 gig of ram 
 4 gig nic cards 
 X drives over 750 gb (they will be added
```

I have looked at LVM and ZFS, either seems to suit me based on this what would you recommend, and why? I am not set on either of those if you guys have something better I am all ears.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Comment: Well, with ZFS as the answer, the answer never becomes outdated. ;)

Comment: @DanielB That's your _opinion_. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although ZFS has more features and is theoretically a more stable file system/volume manager, on a Linux kernel I would use LVM. LVM has been mainstream in the kernel for years and thus is more stable. Every major distribution (including Debian) has out-of-the-box support for it.

ZFS on the other hand is an extension to the kernel that isn't supported by any major distribution. Additionally it hasn't been around as long as LVM. Therefore you could consider it less stable.

LVM would meet all the requirements you wrote in your question. However, if you want to go for the solution with the most features, go ZFS. But keep in mind, if you choose to go with ZFS you would go for a harder to set up, less stable solution.